# Hadoop heart beat and block report time interval

Tags: hadoop, heartbeat

How many seconds once the data node sends heart beat and block report to name node and task tracker sends heart beat and block report to job tracker?

Answer (score 2):

From Apache [documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml), which provides HDFS properties,

`dfs.heartbeat.interval` with a default value of 3 determines datanode heartbeat interval in seconds.

`dfs.blockreport.intervalMsec` with default value of 21600000 determines block reporting interval in milliseconds.

Have a look at above [article](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml) to understanding various HDFS properties.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the heartbeat request to the resource manager is one per second.